# Why is this the interaction energy?

Tags: electrostatics

Why is $\epsilon_0 \int_{\text{all space}} \vec{E_1}.\vec{E_2}  dV$ the interaction energy of two charges bodies, where $\vec{E_1},\vec{E_2}$ are their electric fields at a point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can, in general, write the total energy in the electrostatic field as:

$$
U =  \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int \mathrm{d} V \ | \vec{E} |^2
$$
If there are two sources, superposition gives:
$$
U =  \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int \mathrm{d} V \ | \vec{E}_1 + \vec{E}_2 |^2 \\=  \frac{\epsilon_0}{2} \int \mathrm{d} V \ | \vec{E}_1 |^2 + |\vec{E}_2 |^2 + 2 \vec{E}_1 \cdot \vec{E}_2 \\ 
= U_1 + U_2 + U_\mathrm{int}
$$
This follows simply from how vector multiplication works and the definition of a vector square. The last line is simply me naming all three of my terms: the first two terms are the energies we would get if only $\vec{E}_1$ or $\vec{E}_2$ were present, while the last term only arises when both of them are there. Hence, we call it an interaction energy.